# Having issues with meteorjs app when running with mongodb on localhost

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am having some issues with the MeteorJs app that I am working on. I am working for a client and we are using his dedicated server for our app's deployment. The server has php installed and is already running apache server (a php app is live on server). The server itself is running a version of CentOS.

I bundled my meteor app and uploaded it on server using my cPanel access (it is not root level access). I also created an ssh key and logged into the server using that ssh access.

I used `export` command to set my `MONGO_URL` to `mongodb://localhost:27017/<db-name>` (Version 2.6.3 of MongoDB in installed on server) and `PORT` to `3000`. From here I ran the app using node package "pm2".

Now the issue is that when the app runs it accesses the database for data.

1. The request is made from client side.
2. The server receives the request (seen in the live log)
3. The server fetches data from db and logs it in the terminal.
4. But then it takes somewhere around 10-15 seconds to send that data back to the client.

There is not extra commands or computation between logging the data fetched from server and returning it to client.

But if I change the mongo URI to my instance of MongoLab, everything works fine and there are no delays. My client prefers that the mongo runs on his dedicated server.

As a programmer I know it would be difficult to answer this question with limited information and no hands-on debugging. But I was hoping someone else experienced this issue and was able to resolve. I just installed mongodb on the server without any further configurations. Is it that I need to install any further packages or do any configurations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` to enable oplog tailing feature. when oplog tailing is disabled it takes around 10-15 seconds to send that data to the client.

export `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` like this.

```
MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://localhost/local
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am a bit busy at the moment. Will give it a go as soon as I get free.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Never thought that oplog tailing could have caused the delay.